# Writing a map in Latex

Tags: tables, mathematics

I have a trouble writing a mathematical mapping inside a box written with the \begin{tabular} environment. The map is denoted by · (a dot) and goes from GxG to G (is closed). I'm trying to write the following text inside a table, like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{| c |}
\hline
\begin{align*}
    \cdot \ : \  G \times G & \longmapsto G
    (g,h) & \longmapsto g \cdot h = gh
\end{align*}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

This gives some kind of error when I write the & separator and I don't know why. How can I write this mapping inside my table?

Comment: Can you please add an MWE so we know which document class and packages you are using?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot use `align*` in a table cell.

You can instead use `aligned`, but `tabular` is not needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\boxed{
  \begin{aligned}
    {\cdot} : G \times G & \longrightarrow G \\
    (g,h) & \longmapsto g \cdot h = gh
  \end{aligned}
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Should `\colon` be used in this case?

Comment: @Sigur I changed it to `:` after seeing the result, because of `\cdot`. To be honest, I'd not name the map with `\cdot` (which is not the name of the map, but notation for it).

Comment: I agree. But it is common to find text using such diagram to denote the binary operation. `\cdot\colon` looks ugly... lol